# Android/Web - Deep link works only once, then web page needs to be refreshed to work again

Tags: android, web, deep-linking, intentfilter

I am getting a behavior which I am not sure of how to explain. An application has a deep link with a custom scheme data block in the activity's intent filter. A link click in a web page is responsible for delivering the intent.

Now, this works as intended but only the first time!
Specifically in Android 7 and 8 (older versions seem fine) after the first time the link is clicked instead of the app activity showing, a link of the format `scheme://host/file.html?url=[link to asp file containing the intent function]` is loaded with the header and footer of the web page but no contents (nothing there anyway). If the page is refreshed (button or transition back to it from another page) the link works properly but only once. Need to refresh each time it has been used for it to work again.

I tested the behavior with multiple browsers and it seems to be the same. I am guessing it has something to do with a behavior change in the newer versions of Android (???) but I cannot seem to find what is causing it and whether it is an app (hard), system (probably) or browser (could be?) related issue and as a result a possible solution.

If you think there is any information that might help let me know and I will try to provide it.

Thank you.